# dll issue using Qt in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, dll, libraries

I am a newbie building stuffs on Visual Studio and now I am facing this little problem that I am not able to solve. I correctly installed Qt and used the correct paths on the "VC++ Directories" property of my project (indeed in my code the include are correctly seen). The next step should be to put the correct stuffs in the "linker" of my project.. this is at least what I think the problem consists on. Anyway, I have 100 error of this kind:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: virtual     void __thiscall QObject::disconnectNotify(class QMetaMethod const &)" (__imp_?disconnectNotify@QObject@@MAEXABVQMetaMethod@@@Z) C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: virtual void __thiscall QObject::connectNotify(class QMetaMethod const &)" (__imp_?connectNotify@QObject@@MAEXABVQMetaMethod@@@Z)   C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: virtual void __thiscall QObject::customEvent(class QEvent *)" (__imp_?customEvent@QObject@@MAEXPAVQEvent@@@Z)   C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: virtual void __thiscall QObject::childEvent(class QChildEvent *)" (__imp_?childEvent@QObject@@MAEXPAVQChildEvent@@@Z)   C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: virtual void __thiscall QObject::timerEvent(class QTimerEvent *)" (__imp_?timerEvent@QObject@@MAEXPAVQTimerEvent@@@Z)   C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual bool __thiscall QObject::eventFilter(class QObject *,class QEvent *)" (__imp_?eventFilter@QObject@@UAE_NPAV1@PAVQEvent@@@Z)    C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) double * __cdecl annAllocPt(int,double)" (__imp_?annAllocPt@@YAPANHN@Z)    C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: virtual int __thiscall QImage::metric(enum QPaintDevice::PaintDeviceMetric)const " (__imp_?metric@QImage@@MBEHW4PaintDeviceMetric@QPaintDevice@@@Z) C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class QPaintEngine * __thiscall QImage::paintEngine(void)const " (__imp_?paintEngine@QImage@@UBEPAVQPaintEngine@@XZ)   C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall QImage::setPixel(int,int,unsigned int)" (__imp_?setPixel@QImage@@QAEXHHI@Z)    C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual int __thiscall QImage::devType(void)const " (__imp_?devType@QImage@@UBEHXZ)    C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QImage::~QImage(void)" (__imp_??1QImage@@UAE@XZ)    C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QImage::QImage(int,int,enum QImage::Format)" (__imp_??0QImage@@QAE@HHW4Format@0@@Z) C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) double * * __cdecl annAllocPts(int,int)" (__imp_?annAllocPts@@YAPAPANHH@Z) C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static int __cdecl QApplication::exec(void)" (__imp_?exec@QApplication@@SAHXZ) C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QApplication::~QApplication(void)" (__imp_??1QApplication@@UAE@XZ)  C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QApplication::QApplication(int &,char * *,int)" (__imp_??0QApplication@@QAE@AAHPAPADH@Z)    C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\PhotonMapping\PhotonMapping\main.obj PhotonMapping
```

I know that the problem is stupid but I would like to understand it.. in such a way to learn how to solve it the next time I am going to face it. Thanks in advance!

Enrico

Comment: First off: it is Qt (Q toolkit), not QT (Quick Time). Secondly, why have you not added the libraries? Thirdly, are you using the VS Qt plugin?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and sorry for my mistake. I don't know which libraries I should add. I would say that adding them all would not be nice.. maybe that's the common way but as I said: I am a newbie. I thought there is a specific way to know which libraries I should add according to the above errors. Am I wrong? Anyway, I am not using the VS Qt plugin.